# jQuery check for cookie on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

This is my [website](http://lilaj.al/foot/demo/demo.html).

This is the JQuery code:

```
    (function($){

var MSG_THANK_YOU = 'Thank you for voting!';
var MSG_CANT_VOTE = "You have already voted!";
var MSG_SELECT_ONE = "Please select one option!";

//-----------------------------------------------
// showTip
//-----------------------------------------------
var period_tip_window = 3000;
function showTip( obj, txt, bgcolor )
{
    txt = typeof txt !== 'undefined' ? txt : "Saved！";
    bgcolor = typeof bgcolor !== 'undefined' ? bgcolor : "#60a060";

    var tip_box = obj.find( 'span[ttype="tip_box"]' ).clone();
    if ( !tip_box.length )
    {
        var s = '';
        s += "<span ";
        s += "style='";
        s += "text-align:center;";
        s += "padding:10px;";
        s += "margin:10px;";
        s += "font-size:15px;";
        s += "font-weight:bold;";
        s += "font-style:italic;";
        s += "font-family:times;";
        s += "color:#ffffff;";
        s += "background-color:" + bgcolor + ";";
        s += "border:3px solid #cfcfcf;";
        s += "border-radius: 15px;";
        s += "-moz-border-radius: 15px;";
        s += "-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;";
        s += "-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;";
        s += "'>";
        s += txt;
        s += "</span>";
        tip_box = $( s );
    }

    tip_box.css({
        "position":"absolute",
        "left":"-10000px",
        "top":"-10000px"
    });

    tip_box.appendTo( $( 'body' ) );
    tip_box.show();

    wt = tip_box.outerWidth(false);
    ht = tip_box.outerHeight(true);

    var x = obj.offset().left;
    var y = obj.offset().top;
    var w = obj.width();
    var h = obj.height();

    var ytd = 10;
    var xt = x + w/2 - wt/2;
    var yt = y - ht;

    tip_box.css( { "left":xt + "px", "top":yt + "px" } );
    tip_box.fadeOut( period_tip_window, function() {
        tip_box.remove();
    });
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------
// CWaitIcon
//----------------------------------------------------------------
function CWaitIcon( url_img )
{
    var s = '';
    s += "<img ";
    s += "src='" + url_img + "'";
    s += ">";
    this.img = $( s );

    this.img.css({
        "position":"absolute",
        "left":"-10000px",
        "top":"-10000px"
    });

    this.img.hide();
    this.img.appendTo( $( 'body' ) );
}

CWaitIcon.prototype =
{
    show : function( e )
    {
        var w = 32;
        var h = 32;
        this.img.css( { "left":(e.pageX - w/2) + "px",
            "top":(e.pageY - h/2) + "px" } );
        this.img.show();
    },

    hide : function()
    {
        this.img.hide();
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------
// CCookie
//----------------------------------------------------------------
function CCookie()
{
}

CCookie.prototype =
{
    set : function( name, value, days )
    {
        days = days || 365;
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime( date.getTime() + ( days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ) );
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();

        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    },

    get : function( name )
    {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i < ca.length; i++ )
        {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    },

    del : function( name )
    {
        document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/';
    }
}

var Cookie = new CCookie();

//----------------------------------------------------------------
// CAjaxPoll
//----------------------------------------------------------------
function CAjaxPoll( domobj )
{
    this.domobj = domobj;
    this.form = $( domobj );
    this.tid = this.getAttr( 'tid', domobj );
    this.b_front = true;
    var action = this.getAttr( 'action', domobj );
    this.url_server = action;
    var pos = action.lastIndexOf("/");
    var url_image = 'wait.gif';
    if ( pos != -1 )
    {
        var path = action.substring( 0, pos+1 );
        url_image = path + 'images/' + url_image;
    }
    this.wait_icon = new CWaitIcon( url_image );
}

CAjaxPoll.prototype =
{
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // getAttr
    //-----------------------------------------------
    getAttr : function( id_name, obj )
    {
        if (
            ( typeof( $( obj ).attr( id_name ) ) == 'undefined' ) || 
            ( $( obj ).attr( id_name ) == '' ) // for Opera
        ) return null;
        return $( obj ).attr( id_name );
    },

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // getCookieName
    //-----------------------------------------------
    getCookieName : function()
    {
        return 'ajax_poll_' + this.tid;
    },

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // checkCookie
    //-----------------------------------------------
    checkCookie : function()
    {
        var key = this.getCookieName();
        var s = Cookie.get( key );
        if ( s == null )


        {
            Cookie.set( key, 'yes' );
            $('.ajax-poll-btn-vote').css('display','none');
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    },

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // send
    //-----------------------------------------------
    send : function( item_tid )
    {
        var _this = this;
        $.post( this.url_server,
            { cmd: "vote", form_tid:this.tid, item_tid:item_tid },
            function(data) {
                _this.wait_icon.hide();
                var res = eval('(' + data + ')');
                if ( res.result == 'OK' )
                {
                    _this.items = res.items;
                    _this.displayStats();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert( res.result );
                }
        });
    },

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // run
    //-----------------------------------------------
    run : function()
    {
        var _this = this;

        //-- [BEGIN] Row mouse over
        this.form.find( '.ajax-poll-item' ).mouseover( function() {
            $( this ).addClass( "ajax-poll-item-mover" );
        }).mouseout( function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ajax-poll-item-mover" );
        });
        //-- [END] Row mouse over

        //-- [BEGIN] Setup radio buttons
        this.form.find( '.ajax-poll-item , .ajax-poll-item-radio' ).each( function(){
            var form_tid = _this.tid;
            var item_tid = $(this).attr( 'tid' );
            var radio = $(this).find( '.ajax-poll-item-radio' ).eq(0);
            radio.attr( 'name', form_tid );
            radio.attr( 'value', item_tid );
        });
        //-- [END] Setup radio buttons

        //-- [BEGIN] Select an item
        this.form.find( '.ajax-poll-item, .ajax-poll-item-radio' ).click( function(e){
            //e.preventDefault();
            if ( !_this.b_front ) return;

            var tid = $(this).attr( 'tid' );
            var radio = $(this).find( 'input[value="' + tid + '"]' );
            radio.attr( 'checked', 'checked' );

            _this.form.find( '.ajax-poll-item' )
                .removeClass( "ajax-poll-item-sel" );
            $(this).addClass( "ajax-poll-item-sel" );
        });
        //-- [END] Select an item

        //-- [BEGIN] Vote
        this.form.find( '.ajax-poll-btn-vote' ).click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $(this).parents( '.ajax-poll-form' ).eq(0);

            var item_tid = form.find( 'input[name="' + _this.tid + '"]:checked').val();
            if ( typeof(item_tid) == 'undefined' ) item_tid = '';

            if ( item_tid == '' )
            {
                showTip( form.find( '.ajax-poll-vote-box' ),
                    MSG_SELECT_ONE, "#ff0000" );
                return 
            }
            else
            {
                if ( _this.checkCookie() )
                {
                    showTip( form.find( '.ajax-poll-vote-box' ),
                        MSG_THANK_YOU );
                }
                else
                {
                    showTip( form.find( '.ajax-poll-vote-box' ),
                        MSG_CANT_VOTE, "#ff0000" );
                    return;
                }
            }

            _this.b_front = false;

            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-desc-box' ).hide();

            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-bar' ).css( 'width', 0 );
            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-count' ).html( '' );
            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-perc' ).html( '' );
            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-stats-box' ).show();

            form.find( '.ajax-poll-vote-box' ).hide();
            form.find('.ajax-poll-item-caption ').hide();
            form.find('.ajax-poll-item-sel ').css('background','none');





            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-radio' ).hide();

            _this.vote( e, item_tid );

        });
        //-- [END] Vote

        //-- [BEGIN] View result
        this.form.find( '.ajax-poll-btn-view' ).click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            _this.b_front = false;

            var form = _this.form;
            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-desc-box' ).hide();

            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-bar' ).css( 'width', 0 );
            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-count' ).html( '' );
            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-perc' ).html( '' );
            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-stats-box' ).show();

            form.find( '.ajax-poll-vote-box' ).hide();
            form.find('.ajax-poll-item-caption').hide();


            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-radio' ).hide();
            form.find('.ajax-poll-item-sel ').css('background','none');

            _this.vote( e, '' );

        });
        //-- [END] View result

        //-- [BEGIN] Go Back
        /*this.form.find( '.ajax-poll-btn-back' ).click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            _this.b_front = true;

            var form = _this.form;
            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-desc-box' ).show();
            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-stats-box' ).hide();

            form.find( '.ajax-poll-vote-box' ).show();
            form.find( '.ajax-poll-back-box' ).hide();

            form.find( '.ajax-poll-item-radio' ).show();
        });*/
        //-- [END] Go Back

        //-- [BEGIN] Reset cookie
    /*  this.form.next( '.ajax-poll-btn-reset' ).click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            Cookie.del( _this.getCookieName() );
            alert( "Cookie has been reset!" );
        }); */
        //-- [END] Reset cookie
    },

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // vote
    //-----------------------------------------------
    vote : function( e, item_tid )
    {
        this.wait_icon.show(e);
        this.send( item_tid );
    },

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // displayStats
    //-----------------------------------------------
    displayStats : function()
    {
        var _this = this;

        //-- [BEGIN] Calculate total & Find max count
        var total = 0;
        var max_cnt = 0;
        this.form.find( '.ajax-poll-item' ).each( function(){
            var item_tid = $(this).attr( 'tid' );
            var cnt = 0;
            if ( typeof(_this.items[item_tid]) != 'undefined' )
            {
                cnt = _this.items[item_tid];
            }
            else
            {
                _this.items[item_tid] = cnt;
            }
            if ( max_cnt < cnt ) max_cnt = cnt;
            total += cnt;
        });
        this.form.find( '.ajax-poll-total-value' ).html( total.toString() + ' vote'
                + ( total == 1 ? '' : 's' ) );
        //-- [END] Calculate total & Find max count

        //-- [BEGIN] Find max width
        var max_w = this.form
            .find( '.ajax-poll-item' )
            .eq(0)
            .width();
        max_w = parseInt( max_w );
        //-- [END] Find max width

        //-- [BEGIN] Show counts, percentage, and bar
        this.form.find( '.ajax-poll-item' ).each( function(){
            var tid = $(this).attr( 'tid' );
            var cnt = ( typeof(_this.items[tid]) == 'undefined' ) ?
                0 : _this.items[tid];
            var perc = ( total > 0 ) ?
                ( ( cnt * 100 ) / total ) : 0;

            $(this).find( '.ajax-poll-item-count' ).html( cnt.toString() + ' vote'
                + ( cnt == 1 ? '' : 's' ) );
            $(this).find( '.ajax-poll-item-perc' ).html( perc.toFixed(1) + '%' );

            if ( max_cnt > 0 )
            {
                var w = ( cnt * max_w ) / max_cnt;
                var bar = $(this).find( '.ajax-poll-item-bar' );
                bar.css( 'width', 300 );
                bar.animate({
                    width: w
                }, 1000 );
            }
        });
        //-- [END] Show counts, percentage, and bar
    }
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------
// ready
//----------------------------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '.ajax-poll-form' ).each( function(){
        var obj = new CAjaxPoll( this ); 
        obj.run();

});



});

}(jQuery));
```

How do I first check on page load if the cookies exist for each form and if cookies exist do not display the ".ajax-poll-btn-vote " just the view button.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCookie(cookieName) {
    var i, x, y, cookiesArray = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < cookiesArray.length; i++) {
        x = cookiesArray[i].substr(0, cookiesArray[i].indexOf("="));
        y = cookiesArray[i].substr(cookiesArray[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == cookieName) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

var cookie = getCookie("yourcookiename");
if (cookie != null) {
 ... your code here
}
```

Comment: what should i write in "yourcookiename" ?

Comment: It's the name of the cookie you want to add. You can make it up.